# How can I pass state/object to subroutes (react-router redux)?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-router, reactjs

My 'store.js' does the following:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState = {todos: [], floatBar: {} }) {
 return finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState)
}
```

Then in my 'client.js', I have the intialized states, but didn't define 'todos' array, and set up the Router:

```
let initialState = {
  floatBar: {
    barStatus: false,
    id: 0
  }
}

let store = configureStore(initialState)

render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          path="/"
          component={App}
        >
        <Route
          component={FirstPage}
          path="firstpage"
        />
        <Route
          component={NewPage}
          path="/newpage/:id"
        />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Then in my 'item.js' component, which is a child of 'FirstPage.js', it gets an object 'todo' and retrieves the '.id', which is an object from the 'todos' object-array (inside the render() return{}), I have the following:

```
<Link to={`/newpage/${this.props.todo.id}`}>Link1</Link>
```

Lastly, in my newly linked page, 'NewPage.js', I want to be able to use the same exact 'todo' object in 'item.js', so I can call 'todo.id' and such. How can I do so?

Could anyone show the proper way to do this using redux react-router? Would really appreciate it.

**UPDATE

[image]

**NEWEST UPDATE for actions

actions.js has all of my action creators inside:

```
import * as actions from '../redux/actions'

class NewPage extends Component{
  handleCommentChange(){
    this.props.actions.updateComment()
  }

  render(){
    return()
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapDispatchToProps
)(NewPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to "todo id" from props.params.id . Also you can access to props.params of NewPage through "ownProps" in "mapStateToProps"

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Divider } from 'material-ui'

const styles = {
  title:{
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'left',
    marginLeft: 30
  }
}

class NewPage extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        &nbsp;
        <div style={styles.title}>
          <font size="4">
            {this.props.todo.title}
          </font>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
          <Divider style={{backgroundColor:'#282828'}}/>
        &nbsp;
        <p style={{color: 'white'}}>{this.props.todo.detail}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state, ownProps)=>{
let todo = state.todos.filter(todo=>todo.id==ownProps.params.id);
return{
    todo:todo[0]
}};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewPage);
```

Comment: sorry but is 'let {text, title} = this.props.todo;' setting this.props.todo.text to text and this.props.todo.title to title? And could you clarify what (<Item text={text} title={title} />); is doing? Also should I revise anything in the 'const mapStateToProps'?

Comment: 1.Yes, this is destructuring assignment es6, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. 2 IN <Item text={text} title={title} /> we are passing down props. 3. I can edit that, i have read that you passing todo object to 'Item' component

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As for number 2, shouldn't the NewPage.js be receiving the props from item.js? For 3, if you can I'd appreciate it. Still trying to wrap my head around it. Just to confirm, NewPage.js is attempting to receive the todo object from item.js. So NewPage.js can use 'this.props.todo.text' and 'this.props.todo.title' in item.js.

Comment: @JoKo Item should be a child of NewPage. isn't it? and Item should receive 'todo' object? just for clarify. If yes, then code above fits for you

Comment: Think there's a misunderstanding. item.js is a child of FirstPage.js but NewPage.js needs to receive the 'todo' object from item.js. Inside item.js, <Link to={`/newpage/${this.props.todo.id}`}>Link1</Link>
is defined. But inside NewPage.js, I just would like to use the item.js' this.props.todo.title
this.props.todo.text.

Comment: can you provide a gist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114775/discussion-between-utro-and-jo-ko).

Comment: provided the gist in the chat!

Comment: Came across really strange problem. I've updated the original post with a picture of the log. When I do console.log(this.props) inside NewPage.js which is just renamed to ThreadPage.js, it shows the object with the correct states, such as 'title' and 'detail'(which is renamed from 'text'), but right after when I do console.log(this.props.detail), console.log(this.props.title), they come out to be undefined as you can see. What could be the issue?

Comment: sorry meant to say console.log(this.props.todo.detail), console.log(this.props.todo.title). They both still log undefined as shown in the pic.

Comment: I had to actually do this.props.todo[0].detail. Is there a way to do it with todo.detail alone?

Comment: @JoKo sorry i forgot that filter returns array. I've edited the answer

Comment: Hi Utro! Came across one more issue. How would I use like 'this.props.actions' in this case? Meaning how do I get it passed into NewPage?

Comment: I attempted it with the code that I updated in the original post, but 'this.props.actions' is fetching an object without any methods inside. What may be the issue?

Comment: Getting the following error: Caught TypeError: this.props.actions.updateComment is not a function

Comment: @JoKo in your example you should add 'null'. `export default connect(null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(NewPage);`

Comment: @JoKo [examples of connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples)

Comment: Got it figured out! Thanks. I have one small issue that I need to resolve but I think it would be great if you can help out through a chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

1. Another approach, especially useful for dynamic props, is to clone the child component that gets injected as
   props by React Router, which gives you the opportunity to pass additional props in the process.
   example

```js
class Repos extends Component {
constructor(){...}
componentDidMount(){...}
render() {
let repos = this.state.repositories.map((repo) => (
<li key={repo.id}>
<Link to={"/repos/details/"+repo.name}>{repo.name}</Link>
</li>
));
let child = this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children,
{ repositories: this.state.repositories }
);
return (
<div>
<h1>Github Repos</h1>
<ul>
{repos}
</ul>
{child}
</div>
);
}
}
              
////////////////////////////
class RepoDetails extends Component {
renderRepository() {
let repository = this.props.repositories.find((repo)=>repo.name === this.props.params.
repo_name);
let stars = [];
for (var i = 0; i < repository.stargazers_count; i++) {
stars.push('');
}
return(
<div>
<h2>{repository.name}</h2>
<p>{repository.description}</p>
<span>{stars}</span>
</div>
);
}
render() {
if(this.props.repositories.length > 0 ){
return this.renderRepository();
} else {
return <h4>Loading...</h4>;
}
}
}
```